# Duplicate Key - misleading exception information?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What is the reason of the exception message complains about duplicate key but shows the value instead?

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
employees.add(new Employee("John", 40));
employees.add(new Employee("John", 30));

Map<String, Integer> map = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, Employee::getAge));
```

Instead of show "John" as the duplicated key, it show "40"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 40
    (...)
```

Comment: Interesting indeed

Comment: Probably a bug that was fixed in later versions. When I run this code in Java 10, the exception message is `"Duplicate key John (attempted merging values 40 and 30)"`

Comment: What version did you use?

Comment: @Glains Reproduced it with Java 8.

Comment: It was a bug and fixed in JDK 9. See this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173464

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been fixed in JDK 9. Take a look here. 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173464